# Cant import tensorflow hub i get this error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
```

I get the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow_hub as hub
  File "E:\python64bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
    from tensorflow_hub.estimator import LatestModuleExporter
  File "E:\python64bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\estimator.py", line 62, in <module>
    class LatestModuleExporter(tf.compat.v1.estimator.Exporter):
  File "E:\python64bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\module_wrapper.py", line 193, in __getattr__
    attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v1' has no attribute 'estimator'
```

Comment: Is it possible you don't have the tensorflow-estimnator package installed (a pip dependency of the main tensorflow package)?
If that's not it, please sent repro instructions starting from pip installs in a clean virtualenv.

Comment: What is the output of your pip list?

Comment: Haven't heard from you.
Fix this issue with pip install tensorflow-estimator==2.1.*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever resolved this issue, but I experienced the same issue with the following setup:

```
tensorflow == 2.4.1
tensorflow-hub == 0.12.0
tensorflow-estimator == 2.6.0
```

My solution was to degrade `tensorflow-estimator` to a version < 2.6.0. For example, run `pip install tensorflow-estimator==2.5.*`.
To confirm, run `pip show tensorflow-estimator` to see the current version.

Hope this helps! :)